# Is the minimum fee consensus, just policy, or both?

Tags: transaction-fees, consensus, relay

Intuitively, I think minRelayFee is policy while minBlockTxFee is validation, but `DEFAULT_MIN_RELAY_TX_FEE` is in `validation.h` while `DEFAULT_BLOCK_MIN_TX_FEE` is in `policy.h`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are policy. Both are about the same rule, just concern different parts of the code.

`DEFAULT_MIN_RELAY_TX_FEE` is about transaction relay (don't relay transactions that pay less than `1000` satoshis per kilo-vbyte), while `DEFAULT_BLOCK_MIN_TX_FEE` is about block creation (don't include transactions  paying less than `1000` satoshis per kilo-vbyte in block templates).